# Get Range of a Range for a list of unspecified length?

Tags: c#, range

I'm trying to build up a library of extension methods and would like to integrate using `Range` objects into it where appropriate.

So I've created a class to represent a lightweight view into any arbitrary list and is defined in terms of a given `Range`.

```
public static class ListSlice
{
    public static IReadOnlyList<T> Create<T>(IReadOnlyList<T> list, Range range) => new ListSlice<T>(list, range);
    public static IReadOnlyList<T> Create<T>(IReadOnlyList<T> list, Index start, Index end) => Create(list, new Range(start, end));
}

public class ListSlice<T> : IReadOnlyList<T>
{
    public ListSlice(IReadOnlyList<T> list, Range range)
    {
        (List, Range) = list is ListSlice<T> slice
            ? (slice.List, slice.Range.Apply(range)) // range of range
            : (list, range);
    }
    public IReadOnlyList<T> List { get; }
    public Range Range { get; }

    public T this[int index] => List[Range.GetOffsetAndLength(List.Count).Offset + index];
    public int Count => Range.GetOffsetAndLength(List.Count).Length;

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        var (offset, length) = Range.GetOffsetAndLength(List.Count);
        foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, length))
            yield return List[offset + i];
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}
```

There is one corner case where I want to get a slice of a slice. I could work out the math to calculate the new effective range given the length of the original list... but is it even possible just looking at ranges alone?

As far as I can see, it's pretty straight forward when the ranges have definite starts and ends. But I'm having trouble visualizing how it would work when dealing with ranges that have starts or ends that are relative to the end. How do I do the math for this?

e.g.,

```
// absolute start/end, length is immediately known, difference between the two
0..20    // len: 20
5..10    // len: 5
5..15    // len: 10

// if both starts and ends relative to end, length is still the difference
^20..^0  // len: 20
^15..^10 // len: 5
^15..^5  // len: 10

// how do I get the length if it's open ended?
 0..^10  // len: ???
^5..20   // len: ???
 0..     // len: ??? (equivalent to: 0..^1)
```

I thought maybe using an arbitrary length as a stand in and go from there, I feel like I'm missing some cases.

```
public static class RangeExtensions
{
    public static Range Apply(this Range range, int baseLength, Range subRange)
    {
        var (offset1, length1) = range.GetOffsetAndLength(baseLength);
        var (offset2, length2) = subRange.GetOffsetAndLength(length1);
        return (offset1 + offset2)..(offset1 + offset2 + length2);
    }

    public static Range Apply(this Range range, Range subRange)
    {
        // easy case: (5..10)(..2) -> (5..7)
        // weird case: (5..10)(^2..) -> ???
        var dummyLength = 100; // not sure about this
        var (offset1, length1) = range.GetOffsetAndLength(dummyLength);
        var (offset2, length2) = subRange.GetOffsetAndLength(length1);
        var offset = offset1 + offset2;
        return offset..(offset + length2); // somehow have to offset the dummyLength
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess for the "weird case," the range should be: `(8..)`. Its start is 2 relative to the end of the first slice, which was 10... Maybe it's easier than I'm making it out to be since we're applying the range to the slice...

Comment: Why can't you pass in the length? `Apply(range, List.Count)`

Comment: I do that in the initial implementation, I'm trying to see if it's possible to do this with the ranges alone.

Answer (score 0):

Like you've correctly identified, if `IsFromEnd` match, then you can easily find the result by adding the `Value`s. In the other branches you have to subtract the `inner` offset instead, and set `IsFromEnd` accordingly. Sketching each case on paper helps.

Note: In your other code, you may want to consider the case where a range's start falls after its end.

```
public static Range Within(this Range inner, Range outer)
{
    Index start;

    if (inner.Start.IsFromEnd)
    {
        if (outer.End.IsFromEnd)
            start = ^(outer.End.Value + inner.Start.Value);
        else
            start = outer.End.Value - inner.Start.Value;

    }
    else
    {
        if (outer.Start.IsFromEnd)
            start = ^(outer.Start.Value - inner.Start.Value);
        else
            start = outer.Start.Value + inner.Start.Value;
    }

    Index end;

    if (inner.End.IsFromEnd)
    {
        if (outer.End.IsFromEnd)
            end = ^(outer.End.Value + inner.End.Value);
        else
            end = outer.End.Value - inner.End.Value;
    }
    else
    {
        if (outer.Start.IsFromEnd)
            end = ^(outer.Start.Value - inner.End.Value);
        else
            end = outer.Start.Value + inner.End.Value;
    }

    return start..end;
}
```

Comment: The new range will not exceed the boundaries of the original. I'm trying to keep the semantics the same throughout and the ends typically cannot go beyond the length of the collection. Though it would have been nice if the language supported negative indices or clamping the indices to what's valid natively.